# Display a numeric keypad on activity without an input area

Tags: android, numeric, android-softkeyboard

I use the following code to pop up the soft input keyboard in my Activity

---

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.getInputMethodList();

imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

---

This displays the alphabetic keyboard.

But I want to display the numeric keyboard.

Please note I know that using setInputType() works when used with an Edittext or a TextView but I want to be able to display the keyboard without an input area such as an EditText and simply listen to the key presses on the keyboard.

Can anyone confirm whether this is possible and if so how can it be achieved?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try using the "onKeyDown" methods, I use them for capturing the "back" hard key on phones in my application, an example of the method, using back as the button its listening for, would be

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
      if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEY_BACK)){
          back();
      }
         return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
   }
```

But instead of using KeyEvent.KEY_BACK, try using KeyEvent.KEYCODE_P instead. I'm not possitive if this will work on a soft keyboard, but its worth a shot! good luck

Comment: Hi Samuel, sorry I should have been more clear, I can successfully capture the keys but my issus is that the keyboard is aphabetical and I want it to pop up as numeric

Comment: alright, to further help, can you tell me exactlly what elements you are using on your xml? or whats being accomplished here?

Comment: You ever find an answer to this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed achievable and possible.

## TL;DR:

Override `onCreateInputConnection` and request a numeric keypad:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    [your methods here]

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection connection =  super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        return connection;
    }
}
```

## Full Explanation

You've subclassed `View` to create your own custom view:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    [your methods here]
}
```

Within this custom view, you're using the [`InputMethodManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html) to show the keyboard. This manager is going to delegate input to an [`InputConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputConnection.html), which will then delegate to an [`InputMethod`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethod.html).

To request that they keyboard shown is numeric, you'll want to override [`onCreateInputConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onCreateInputConnection(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo)) to return a numeric keypad. You could go to the trouble and implement your own [`BaseInputConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/BaseInputConnection.html), or you could just reuse the one created for you by `super` (in this case, `View`) and set the property you care about (`inputType`).

Comment: Perfect thought !!! 
Did you test the same code ? I followed your answer but I didn't get success?