# Display numeric keyboard in Activity default run time

Tags: android, keyboard, android-context, numeric, android-input-method

Application has activity which has no widget like textview,EditText,button.

I want to achieve this by programmatically.(run time)
I successfully able to display system keyboard with below code.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

     imm.showSoftInput(getWindow().getDecorView(), 0);
```

I want to show the numeric keyboard instead of the the qwerty default keyboard.

can anybody have idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of custom view you can achieve like this, Normally with InputMethodManager you can show the keyboard. This manager is going to delegate input to an InputConnection, which will then delegate to an InputMethod.

so make a custom view which perform like that..

```
public class MyCustomView extends View {

    ..your methods here..

    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection inputConnection =  super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        return inputConnection;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: I already read this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980510/display-a-numeric-keypad-on-activity-without-an-input-area?rq=1 but  It didn't work. Did you try this ?

Answer (score 0):

You cant set inputType to the InputMethodManager. But the workaround I came across is to put an edittext in the layout and set inputType as Number in xml and hide that view. Then at runtime use this edittext to show numeric keyboard.
Like :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(your_edittext, 0);
```

Comment: For Android application pointof you we can do this,but  as I told you it's not possible to put any widget into this. I am working regarding JNI portion

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```