# How to disable autocomplete/suggest when using InputMethodManager.showSoftKeyboard()

Tags: android, libgdx

Trying to fix a bug in my LibGDX app where some Android users are reporting the spacebar is inserting "autocomplete" words into their input. In some cases, the soft keyboard does not even display autocomplete suggestions.

From what I understand, LibGDX doesn't use "native" Android UI elements, so a `TextField` object runs this code on click:

```
public void setOnscreenKeyboardVisible (final boolean visible) {
        handle.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (visible) {
                    View view = ((AndroidGraphics)app.getGraphics()).getView();
                    view.setFocusable(true);
                    view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    manager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
                } else {
                    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(((AndroidGraphics)app.getGraphics()).getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So there's this line here which shows the keyboard:

```
manager.showSoftInput(view, 0);
```

How can I set some flags or something to tell the keyboard to disable autocomplete?

Note, this only happens with some users, can't find a pattern. Also, Android 8 and 9 only, so far.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a bit and it turns out this is not straightforward at all.

The method from `AndroidInput` that you showed uses the view `app.getGraphics().getView()` to show the keyboard. As explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831349/5288316), you would need to subclass that view and override the following method to be able to set the input flags:

```java
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    InputConnection connection =  super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    // Set flags to disable suggestions. Visible password flag is only needed for some devices.
    outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS 
            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
    return connection;
}
```

Except the view used by `AndroidGraphics` is not especially easy to subclass. Instead, you could subclass the `AndroidInput` class and provide a different view for input. Here's an example launcher class:

```java
class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

    private View inputView;
    private Handler handle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Config and init your game class.
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(new MyGame(), config);

        // Custom view used for showing the keyboard.
        // Most of the code in onCreateInputConnection comes from the GLSurfaceView20 class.
        inputView = new View(this) {
            @Override
            public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
                if (outAttrs != null) {
                    outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI;
                    // This line is the only different from original source, it disables suggestions.
                    outAttrs.inputType |= InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
                            | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD;
                }

                return new BaseInputConnection(this, false) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean deleteSurroundingText (int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
                        int sdkVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
                        if (sdkVersion >= 16) {
                            if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
                                sendDownUpKeyEventForBackwardCompatibility(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
                    }

                    @TargetApi(16)
                    private void sendDownUpKeyEventForBackwardCompatibility (final int code) {
                        final long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                        super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, code, 0, 0,
                                KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE));
                        super.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, code, 0, 0,
                                KeyCharacterMap.VIRTUAL_KEYBOARD, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE));
                    }
                };
            }
        };
        handle = new Handler();  // handle is private in AndroidInput so we create our own.

        // Android has two different AndroidInput classes depending on SDK versions, create the right one. You can remove one of them if you don't support API < 12.
        if (Build.VERSION.PREVIEW_SDK_INT >= 12) {
           input = new AndroidInputThreePlus(this, this, graphics.getView(), config) {
               @Override
               public void setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(boolean visible) {
                   AndroidLauncher.this.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(visible);
               }
           };
        } else {
            input = new AndroidInput(this, this, graphics.getView(), config) {
                @Override
                public void setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(boolean visible) {
                    AndroidLauncher.this.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(visible);
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private void setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(final boolean visible) {
        // Code comes from AndroidInput.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible except view is changed.
        handle.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run () {
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (visible) {
                    inputView.setFocusable(true);
                    inputView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    manager.showSoftInput(inputView, 0);
                } else {
                    manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(inputView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So as you can see, this is not exactly easy to do. I haven't tested it either so there might me more things missing.

At that point I would rather suggest you to file an issue on github and make a pull request. The android graphics view implementation is the `GLSurfaceView20` (or `GLSurfaceView20API18`) and it already overrides `onCreateInputConnection`. You could add an option to disable suggestions in the `Input` interface and implement it on every backend.

If you have any question about this don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: thank you for this concise answer and for taking the time to put it together, I'm going to mess with it today and see what happens, if it works a pull request for easier control would be a good idea

Comment: Oof at delay finally getting around to implementing this. Once again great concise answer. Only unfortunate thing is the keyboard isn't popping. I'm still messing around but yeah, the `showSoftInput` call with `inputView` isn't working, replacing those 3 lines of code with the old code utilizing `getGraphics().getView()` and it works, so all class/subclass replacements are in order, it's just the call itself combo with the new View that isn't playing nice.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the view isn't in any Window. Try adding the view to the activity layout it might work.

Comment: apologies for being a bit dense but how would I do that? I've been at it trying to figure it out to no avail, I always get messed up with views/activities/windows and their XML components Android seems to be built on (LibGDX is top level enough to never have to deal with it...)

Comment: this was a shot in the dark but either its not the right code to add a view, or this was right but still didn't work :/ `((ViewGroup)((AndroidGraphics)_app.getGraphics()).getView().getParent()).addView(_inputView);`

Comment: I'll look into it in a few hours. It might not be the problem too...

Comment: Thanks. I'm still messing with it. I actually tried another roundabout way by subclassing AndroidGraphics instead, and just adding the required keyboard flags to its View creation...but couldn't properly get it implemented bc of package private class members when going that route...

Comment: Just tried it... I don't see a solution for now. If your game is not too centered on text input, you could do what many others do instead: show a native dialog when a TextField is focused. This creates an overall better text editing experience since the dialog moves with the keyboard, user can copy&paste, etc.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the time you put in. I'm going to yell at the LibGDX devs to simply add an option to add those keyboard flags to the Graphics-created VIew because it's really that simple.